# Windows 8 show all background tasks

Tags: windows-8

Is there a way (by hand, manually) to list all background tasks currently registered on my machine, along with their details such as the the triggers that they response to, the app that they originated from, and so on?

Also, when I uninstall an app, will all background task that that app registered also removed (i.e unregistered)?

Comment: are you talking about from a WinRt app or from a desktop app? You can't access it from Windows Store Apps, only a desktop app using the method JP showed below. Just to clarify : )

Comment: it's ok, I just need to do it by hand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look in the registry under ...

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.BackgroundTasks

Each package with a Background Task associated with it will have an `ActivatableClassId` (but unfortunately, it seems all packages are listed).  Also, you can look under ...

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ActivatableClasses\Package

For Packages that have an `ExePath` of `backgroundTaskHost.exe`.  Yes, background tasks are removed when you uninstall a package.